# Inheriting group permissions in Django UserProfile models

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

Suppose I have a project where I know in advance that I will only have three user groups. Can I define them in advance inheriting from a GroupParent and then add a field to my UserProfile with these group choices?? This is basically what I'd like to do:

```
class GroupParent(??):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('do_something', 'Can do something'),
            ('edit_task', 'Can edit task'),
     );

class GroupAdmin(GroupParent):
    class Meta:
        // I want to inherit the permissions from the Mixin and add a few
        // I know this would only overwrite... how do I do it?
        permissions = (
            ('do_fancy_tasks', 'Can do fancy tasks'),
         )

class GroupCoordinator(GroupParent):
     class Meta:
     // inherit from GroupParent and add my own
         permissions = (
            ('open_file', 'Can open files'),
         )

class GroupNormal(GroupParent):
     class Meta:
     // inherit from GroupParent and add my own
         permissions = (
            ('open_file', 'Can open files'),
            ('edit_file', 'Can edit files'),
         )

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    has_manager = models.BooleanField()
    ...
    ...
    group = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GROUP_CHOICES) // how??
```

Is this even a reasonable approach or should I just give up and set up groups+permissions once the app is built (or as I'm building it)?

Also... what's the advantage to using django-guardian over django's default permission capabilities and what should I keep in mind if I plan to use it with these models? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about simple tuple addition?

```
class GroupParent(object):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('do_something', 'Can do something'),
            ('edit_task', 'Can edit task'),
        )

class GroupAdmin(GroupParent):
    class Meta:
        permissions = GroupParent.Meta.permissions + (
            ('do_fancy_tasks', 'Can do fancy tasks'),
         )
```

This is alright since GroupParent is just a mixin. If GroupParent was a Django model, you would have to use `GroupParent._meta.permissions`.